# cut a field from its position & place it in different position

Tags: shell, awk

I have 2 files - file1 & file2 with contents as shown.

```
cat file1.txt

1,2,3

cat file2.txt

a,b,c
```

& the desired output is as below,

```
a,1,b,2,c,3
```

Can anyone please help to achieve this?

Till now i have tried this,

```
paste -d "," file1.txt file2.txt|cut -d , -f4,1,5,2,6,3
```

& the output came as 1,2,3,a,b,c

But using 'cut' is not the good approach i think.
Becuase here i know there are 3 values in both files, but if the values are more, above command will not be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[FNR,i]=$i};next} {printf("%s,%s",a[FNR,1],$1);for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf(",%s,%s",a[FNR,i],$i)};print ""}' file2.txt  file1.txt
```

OR(a NON-one liner form of solution too as follows)

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{                      ####making field separator as , then putting FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first file named file1.txt will be read by awk.
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){            ####Starting a for loop here which will run till the total number of fields value from i=1.
        a[FNR,i]=$i                    ####creating an array with name a whose index is FNR,i and whose value is $i(fields value).
                          };
        next                           ####next will skip all further statements, so that second file named file2.txt will NOT read until file1.txt is completed.
                }
                {
        printf("%s,%s",a[FNR,1],$1);   ####printing the value of a very first element of each lines first field here with current files first field.
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){            ####starting a for loop here till the value of NF(number of fields).
        printf(",%s,%s",a[FNR,i],$i)   ####printing the values of array a value whose index is FNR and variable i and printing the $i value too here.
                          };
        print ""                       ####printing a new line here.
                }
        ' file2.txt  file1.txt         ####Mentioning the Input_files here.
```

Answer (score 0):

paste -d "," file*|awk -F, '{print $4","$1","$5","$2","$6","$3}'

a,1,b,2,c,3

This is simple printing operation. Other answers are most welcome.
But if the file contains 1000's of values, then this printing approach will not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { split($0,a); next }
    {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s%s%s", $i, OFS, a[i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
' file1 file2
a,1,b,2,c,3
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ paste -d, file2 file1 |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        n=NF/2
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            printf "%s%s%s%s", $i, OFS, $(i+n), (i<n?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
'
a,1,b,2,c,3
```